# Choosing shapefile interactively in R

Tags: shapefile, r, maptools

I am writing a function in R where I want the user to choose an Esri shapefile from its destination folder. Since a shapefile is made of several files how can I select them. For a point feature class I used readShapePoints()

```
 data =  readShapePoints(file.choose())
```

OR

```
 data =  readShapePoints(choose.files())
```

Do i need to zip files which than can be selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has too many brackets for one thing. I count three `(` and two `)`.

Fix that, and using `file.choose()` should work if the user chooses the `.shp` file.

Note that:

- `file.choose()` only produces a dialog on Windows (I think) - on Linux its a text prompt. I don't know if it works in RStudio...
- The `maptools` functions `readShape*` usually fail to read coordinate reference systems in the `.prj` file of the shapefile, and so should be avoided. The fix is to use `readOGR` from the `rgdal` package, but then you have to specify the folder and the filename as two arguments. Your chooser will probably give you a full path to the shapefile component, and the `pathological` package in R will help you split the components into path and filename.